# Custom cron job filename for a package

Tags: cron, packaging, deb

I'm willing to create a cron job for a package but when I define it in `debian/cron.d` it gets installed as `/etc/cron.d/package`. I'd prefer to be able to change the name of the cron job to be something like `/etc/cron.d/foobar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [`man dh_installcron`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dh_installcron.1.html):

```
--name=name
   Look for files named debian/package.name.cron.* and install them as
   etc/cron.*/name, instead of using the usual files and installing
   them as the package name.
```

So name your `debian/package-name.foobar.cron.d`, and add to `debian/rules`:

```
override_dh_installcron:
    dh_installcron --name=foobar
```

Comment: lol, I should had read the dh_installcron man page before, thanks!